# Content inside kinetic object

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

Is' there any way to push some content(images,other figures) into Kinetic.js figure without overriding drawFunc?

Comment: Yeah, you could just use the canvas functions alongside kineticsjs. The problem would be that you have to create a function for that figure so that each time the canvas is redrawn, your figure will be as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially no, you would have to extend the framework so that you can group things together.

or just use :

```
Kinetic.Group();
```

to group things together into one object.